# jUnit testing @RequestParam, but my test doesn't give any value to it

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit

How can I test requested parameters which are coming from HTML to Spring controller?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "foo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String Foo(@RequestParam(value="bar", required=false) String bar{

if(bar==null || bar.length()==0){
   return "error";
}

    return "success";   
}
```

I don't understand why this isn't working?

```
@Test
public void testFoo() throws Exception {
   mockMvc.perform(post("/foo")
            .param("bar", "this is not null"))
            .andExpect(view().name("success"));
}
```

I get:
java.lang.AssertionError: View name expected:"success" but was:"error"

So I want that my controller test skips the validation part and goes to "success", but somehow my test isn't giving value to my bar variable. How to make this work?

Comment: Your assertion error doesn't look like it matches what you're actually asserting...

Comment: We can't really trust your code when it doesn't compile and when the results don't match what you're describing.

Comment: Oh, sorry guys. I accidentally swapped the values of assertionerror. It's now edited.

Comment: The code of the controller is also invalid. Why don't you post the real code?

Comment: I tried to simplify it. Demonstrating my issue doesn't need much of a code so I tried to make it as readable as it can be. Apparently I failed. I don't see what's wrong with controller.

Comment: It lacks a parenthesis. The problem is that the assertion error you get doesn't come from a test of the code you posted (since it doesn't compile), but from the test of code we don't know anything about.